# How to run mocha and node together

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I'm working on mocha to do unit testing for my API's, My requirement is to run mocha first and if mocha gets success it should node next in a single command.

Now we are using **npm test** to run mocha and **node server** to start the server separately. But it should happen in a single command

Comment: npm run test && node server

Comment: Or check out https://github.com/bahmutov/start-server-and-test

Comment: @Yecodeo if I run npm run test itself it will start the server, my requirement is to stop the server if mocha test result having failing APIs in response.